# Fastest way to replace phrases from sentences with Python?

Tags: replace

I have a list of 3800 names I want to remove from 750K sentences.
The names can contain multiple words such as "The White Stripes".
Some names might also be look like a subset of a larger name, ex: 'Ame' may be one name and 'Amelie' may be another.
This is what my current implementation looks like:

```py
def find_whole_word(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search


names_lowercase = ['the white stripes', 'the beatles', 'slayer', 'ame', 'amelie'] # 3800+ names

def strip_names(sentence: str):
    token = sentence.lower()
    has_name = False
    matches = []
    for name in names_lowercase:
        match = find_whole_word(name)(token)
        if match:
            matches.append(match)

    def get_match(match):
        return match.group(1)

    matched_strings = list(map(get_match, matches))
    matched_strings.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    for matched_string in matched_strings:
        # strip names at the start, end and when they occur in the middle of text (with whitespace around)
        token = re.sub(rf"(?<!\S){matched_string}(?!\S)", "", token)
    return token

sentences = [
 "how now brown cow", 
 "die hard fan of slayer", 
 "the white stripes kill", 
 "besides slayer I believe the white stripes are the best",
 "who let ame out",
 "amelie has got to go"
] # 750K+ sentences

filtered_list = [strip_names(sentence) for sentence in sentences]

# Expected: filtered_list = ["how now brown cow", "die hard fan of ", " kill", "besides I believe  are the best", "who let out", " has got to go"]
```

My current implementation takes several hours. I don't care about readability as this code won't be used for long.

Any suggestions on how I can increase the run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous solution was overkill.
All I really had to do was use the word boundary `\b` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters).

Usage example: https://regex101.com/r/2CZ8el/1

[image]

```py
import re

names_joined = "|".join(names_lowercase)

names_whole_words_filter_expression = re.compile(rf"\b({names_joined})\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def strip_names(text: str):
    return re.sub(names_whole_words_filter_expression, "", text).strip()
```

Now it takes a few minutes instead of a few hours